# I am getting an error while using the buildozer

Tags: python, buildozer

I am trying to build an apk android with buildozer and I came across an error.

I've followed the instructions in the Kivy documentation page but still getting this error. Any advice is must appreciated. Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSKYp.png)[image][image][image][image][image]

```
kivy@kivy-VirtualBox:~/Downloads$ buildozer android debug
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Create directory /home/kivy/Downloads/.buildozer
# Create directory /home/kivy/Downloads/bin
# Create directory /home/kivy/Downloads/.buildozer/applibs
# Create directory /home/kivy/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform
# Create directory /home/kivy/Downloads/.buildozer/android/app
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian `dpkg' package management program version 1.17.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git clone -b master --single-branch https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git python-for-android'
# Cwd /home/kivy/Downloads/.buildozer/android/platform
Cloning into 'python-for-android'...
# Run '/usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\''
# Cwd None
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 257, in run
    InstallRequirement.from_line(name, None))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 172, in from_line
    return cls(req, comes_from, url=url, prereleases=prereleases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 70, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2667, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2605, in parse_requirements
    line, p, specs = scan_list(VERSION,LINE_END,line,p,(1,2),"version spec")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2573, in scan_list
    raise ValueError("Expected "+item_name+" in",line,"at",line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'enum34; python_version<"3.4"', 'at', '; python_version<"3.4"')

Storing debug log for failure in /tmp/tmpOpFqx8
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python2.7 -m pip install -q --user 'appdirs' 'colorama>=0.3.3' 'jinja2' 'six' 'enum34; python_version<"3.4"' 'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"'
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     _LXSESSION_PID = '1437'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/kivy'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     UPSTART_EVENTS = 'started xsession'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     LC_PAPER = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     LOGNAME = 'kivy'
#     USER = 'kivy'
#     HOME = '/home/kivy'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     PATH = '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1396'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     TERM = 'xterm'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/kivy/.Xauthority'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_US'
#     INSTANCE = ''
#     LC_MONETARY = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/Lubuntu.mandatory.path'
#     JOB = 'dbus'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     UPSTART_INSTANCE = ''
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     SESSION = 'Lubuntu'
#     SESSIONTYPE = 'lxsession'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     SELINUX_INIT = 'YES'
#     XDG_CONFIG_HOME = '/home/kivy/.config'
#     SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN = 'gtk'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/ssh-4QKD1v3dGi0x/agent.1391'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     GDMSESSION = 'Lubuntu'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     UPSTART_JOB = 'lxsession'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/lubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/usr/share/gdm:/var/lib/menu-xdg:/usr/share/Lubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'LXDE'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c1'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-aTHfYdXDc6'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'Lubuntu'
#     UPSTART_SESSION = 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1285'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/lubuntu:/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/Lubuntu.default.path'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/kivy'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_US'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     PWD = '/home/kivy/Downloads'
#     SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER = 'upstart'
#     LC_NAME = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'lxde-'
#     LC_TIME = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: Add your error message as text, not as an image.

Comment: Hi @KlausD., I changed the post.